# How can I understand a servo well enough to build one?

Tags: integrated-circuit, datasheet, servo

I am trying to understand exactly how a servo works, so that I can build one.

I bought and built a small robot arm kit, and it has five geared DC motors to actuate it. I would like to control the robot arm from a computer, but in order to do that, I need to make the actuators smarter, essentially turning them into servos.

I opened up a couple of inexpensive analog RC servos, and the design looks simple. It has a dc motor, a potentiometer on the output shaft, and circuitry to turn the PWM signal to a position for the output shaft.

My problem is that after opening a couple of servos, I got a range of controller chip models ranging from KC2462 to KC8801. These all seem to be made by the same [Chinese company](http://www.kcsemitech.com/). Unfortunately, I can't find the data sheets, and even if I did, I do not understand any Chinese dialect.

My question can be summed up as this:

- Is there another servo control chip datasheet that I can read?
- Is there a website with enough information to learn how exactly a typical analog servo does what it does?
- Is there perhaps a book with the above information?

Please understand that I already understand how I could hack a servo motor together - I can reprogram an ATtiny45 to take some kind of positional input from one pin, an analog input from a potentiometer on the output shaft, and then output direction and speed to the DC motor. Speed accomplished with PWM in this case. Maybe with a huge cap on the supply to ensure the DC motor doesn't cause too big of a voltage drop when it starts moving.

However, I don't know if the above would damage the chip with inductive feedback from the motor, or if there's a different way to do the speed control.

I would like to understand how the problem is solved in a real-life professionally designed and built servo motor.

As for my background, I did some electronics in school, and I've been playing with Arduino and ATtiny45/85 microcontrollers for a few weeks.

Comment: What's missing from your ATtiny solution is an H bridge to drive the motor, catch diodes, and some supply filtering.  Openservo v1.1 at http://openservo.com/Schematic seems like an example of what you want to do and is ATtiny based, while their current design uses an ATmega168.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - You should add this as an answer. An open design for building your own servo seems to be a pretty good answer to what I'm asking.

Comment: Perhaps in an ideal world, but there's a strong bias against link-only answers here, and any quick summary would be inferior to the information found at the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another RC servo IC was made by Signetics - the [NE544](http://www.datasheetarchive.com/NE544-datasheet.html) (and some similar models, perhaps NE5044) for which quite a bit of information can be found.

This is the old style pulse width control which is easy to generate and still seems to be quite common; I don't know anything about newer "digital" servo interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

[OpenServo (Internet Archive link)](https://web.archive.org/web/20180413155035/https://openservo.org/) **was** an open hardware project that aims to upgrade a servo by replacing the controller board. The chip they use is some variant of the ATtiny chips.

The [board designs are still available](https://web.archive.org/web/20180611030451/https://github.com/ginge/OpenServo) in Github.

Sparkfun **used to** sell a [custom implementation of these boards](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9014).

Comment: openservo.com no longer exists, and the sparkfun product is now discontinued. Might not be a bad idea to update this answer.

Comment: This is why link only answers are bad.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the datasheet: http://www.kcsemitech.com/upLoad/down/month_1403/201403091839011423.pdf
You can use google translate to get some info out of it, but some data is in english.

Answer (score 1):

"*Is there perhaps a book with the above information?*"

I think, there are many books in Control Theory/Control Systems describing servo loops.

Examples: Classical Feedback Control (B.J. Lurie); Modern Control Systems (R. Dorf, R. Bishop).

Don`t overlook the importance to select a suitable controller/compensator for ensuring closed-loop stability with a good step response (without ringing) at the same time.

**Comment** (edit): The transfer function of a dc motor (Output rotation angle-to-input voltage) can be approximated by an I-T2 function (integrate with two first-order delay elements). Hence, compensation with a PD-T1 controller works good.

Answer (score 0):

> Please understand that I already understand how I could hack a servo motor together - I can reprogram an ATtiny45 to take some kind of positional input from one pin, an analog input from a potentiometer on the output shaft, and then output direction and speed to the DC motor. Speed accomplished with PWM in this case.

That's not hacking a servo. That *is* a servo. Sure, rc servos are a commodity now and there are all-in-one chips to control them, but there is no secret sauce. They're doing exactly what you described.

Add to your description a motor driver of some kind, and a PID loop between the input and output and you have a servo that's exactly the same as a commercial one.

Once you've got that down, your questions are no longer servo specific, they're things like: "how do I tune a PID loop" or "how do I make a compact circuit board".